# Convert day, week number, and year to Date in VB

Tags: vb.net

I need help converting year, week number, and day to date.  So if date1 is 1990, wN is 12, and dDay is 3 the result should be 3/21/1990 (mm/dd/yyyy format).

I am having issue finding the right format to this line: `Output(Date(date1, 1, 1) + ((wN - 1) * 7) - Weekday(Date(date1, 1, 1) + (wN - 1) * 7, 2) + 1 + (dDay - 1))`

This code works well in Excel.  I am trying to convert this to work in vb.net

```
    Dim str1 As String = txtInput1.Text
    Dim d2 As String
    Dim date1 As Integer
    Dim date2 As Integer
    Dim wN As Integer
    Dim dDay As Integer

    Dim cYear As Integer = DateTime.Now.Year

    txtOutput.Text = ""

    d2 = Mid(str1, 2, 1)
    wN = Mid(str1, 3, 2)
    dDay = Mid(str1, 5, 1)

    If d2 = "G" Then
        date1 = 1990
        date2 = 2013
        If date2 <= cYear Then
            'Output("Year Built " & date1 & " or " & date2 & vbCrLf & "Week " & wN & vbCrLf & "Day " & dDay)
            Output(Date(date1, 1, 1) + ((wN - 1) * 7) - Weekday(Date(date1, 1, 1) + (wN - 1) * 7, 2) + 1 + (dDay - 1))
        Else
            Output("Year Built " & date1)
        End If
```

Comment: something like `DateTime.Parse`
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula is a bit off. Start at the beginning of the year and add the number of days.

```
    Const DAYS_IN_A_WEEK As Integer = 7

    Dim year As Integer = 1990
    Dim weekNumber As Integer = 12
    Dim dayOfWeek As Integer = 3

    Dim calculatedDate = New DateTime(year, 1, 1)
    calculatedDate = calculatedDate.AddDays((weekNumber - 1) * DAYS_IN_A_WEEK + (dayOfWeek - 1) - (CInt(calculatedDate.DayOfWeek) - 1))
```

Comment: I needed to be more specific.  The formula needs to include the weekday function with Monday as the first day of week.  So if year 2013 and week and day the same would equal = 4/9/2013.  The above returns the 10th for 2013.

Comment: @VBANewbie I added the day of the week